# Communicaing between Android ADB and a custom AOSP build?

Tags: android, adb, android-source

I am running a custom AOSP build on the emulator and I am logging certain things from my modified ART. I then retrieve the results via adb logcat.

But the log is being spammed which makes things very slow. It would be great if I could somehow via ADB communicate the pid of the app I am interest in monitoring so that I could do filtering in place inside the runtime.

There is a way to do

Code:

```
adb setprop mypid 1234
```

in ADB, which can then be retrieved in the code via
Code:

```
property_get("mypid"....)
```

BUT this does not appear to work on emulator builds, only on real hardware.

**My question: What other way is there really?**

Second question: Where is the documentation about the API available in the runtime itself? Certainly there has to be a documented API somewhere... but I cant find it. I have guessed getpid() correctly on my own.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch `adb logcat -c` to clean the cache, then `adb logcat` regularly, note your PID and then just `adb logcat | grep *your_pid*`.

But it's better if you use your own TAG in logs and grep by it `adb logcat -s *TAG_NAME*`.

If you are not in LINUX, but in Windows, grep will not work right away. But you can check [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/300815/grep-equivalent-for-windows-7) for further info on that.